Using `coord_flip` with `facet_nested`
Here is a MWE:
Here is some data:
data <- 
structure(list(cilow = c(0.0528306698161456, 0.0708961798923575, 
-0.0860844842473584, 0.149293656874665, 0.175348742108531, 0.00150087452513042
), fullest = c(0.194641049761067, 0.282228250041396, 0.107053849480737, 
0.296390973553158, 0.38517505087032, 0.205531742216253), cihigh = c(0.336451429705988, 
0.493560320190435, 0.300192183208833, 0.443488290231651, 0.595001359632109, 
0.409562609907376), regressor = c("1. Plant 1", "2. Plant 2", 
"3. Plant 3", "4. Plant 4", "5. Plant 5", "6. Plant 6"), group = c("A. Green", 
"A. Green", "A. Green", "B. Blue", "B. Blue", "C. Red"), title = c("(i) Flowers", 
"(i) Flowers", "(i) Flowers", "(i) Flowers", "(ii) Trees", "(ii) Trees"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

This is what I have tried so far:
ggplot(data, aes(forcats::fct_rev(regressor), fullest)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.3) +
    geom_errorbar(
      aes(ymin = cilow, ymax = cihigh),
      width = 0, size = 0.8) +
    geom_point(
      show.legend = F) +
    theme_bw() +
    facet_nested(. ~ group + title, scales = "free", space = "free")
    facet_wrap(. ~ group, cols = 1)

I would like to flip this around such that there is 1 column of 3 facets, stacked on top of each other. The first-level "group" facet titles should be horizontal and at the top of each facet. The second level titles ("title") should be vertical and connect the relevant facets on their left side. The "regressor" names should be on the right hand side. Is there a way to achieve this coord-flip with the nested titles?

The title mentions coord_flip, which will swap x/y within each facet, but has nothing to do with the arrangement of facets. Do you want to flip both?

Here's a bit of a hack using patchwork and semi-manually defined sub-plots.
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

plot_facet <- function(grp_no) {
  data |>
    group_by(group) |>
    filter(group_indices() == grp_no) |>
ggplot(aes(forcats::fct_rev(regressor), fullest)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.3) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = cilow, ymax = cihigh),
    width = 0, size = 0.8) +
  geom_point(
    show.legend = F) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  ggh4x::facet_nested(title ~ group, scales = "free", space = "free", switch = "y")
}

plot_facet(1) /
  plot_facet(2) /
  plot_facet(3)


Or with   ggh4x::facet_nested(.~ group + title , scales = "free",  space = "free", switch = "y")

The more built-in (for ggh4x::facet_nested) would be to have the group and title headers in the same region of the plot:
ggplot(data, aes(forcats::fct_rev(regressor), fullest)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.3) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = cilow, ymax = cihigh),
    width = 0, size = 0.8) +
  geom_point(
    show.legend = F) +
  theme_bw() +
  ggh4x::facet_nested(group + title~., scales = "free", space = "free", switch = "y")



Thanks. This needs to be flipped so that the coef plots/CI bars are horizontal not vertical. Also, the "space = "free"" argument doesn't seem to be working in the bottom plot.
